# Load a directory of resource files in WPF WebBrowser

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, shdocvw

I have a directory of HTML files and images added as resources in Visual Studio; these files link to each other.

I can load any one of them as a stream or string and load them up into the WebBrowser, but if I do that, hyperlinks between the files break, because the document no longer knows that it's in a directory with other files.

I don't want to load the files as file:// URLs on disk, because they also contain JavaScript; by default IE blocks them from running active content.

How do I load these files in a WPF WebBrowser?

Comment: did you try relative path?